# Have a Python CGI call a Perl CGI, passing original info (to limit searching private Mailman archives to logged-in users)

Tags: python, cgi, mailman

I need to have a Python CGI script do some stuff (a little bit of security checking), and then end up calling a Perl CGI script, passing anything it received (e.g., POST info) onto the Perl script.

For background, my reason for doing this is that I'm trying to integrate Swish searching with Mailman list archives.

Swish searching uses swish.cgi, a Perl script, but because these are private list archives I can't just allow people to call swish.cgi directly as recommended on this page: http://wpkg.org/Integrating_Mailman_with_a_Swish-e_search_engine#Mailman_configuration

I believe what I need to do is have the Mailman "private" cgi-bin file (written in Python) do its regular security checking (which calls a few Mailman/python modules) and THEN call on swish.cgi to do the search (after having verified that the user is on the mailing list).

Essentially, I believe the simplest solution would just be to protect access to the swish.cgi Perl script with a variant of the standard mailman cgi-bin/private Python script.

(I considered the idea that people could search with a non-protected swish.cgi, and people wouldn't be able to view the full results because those posts are already password-protected by default Mailman setup... but the problem is that even showing the Swish post excerpts in the search results could expose confidential information, so I must restrict access to even the search itself to just subscribers.)

If someone has a better idea of how to solve the overall problem without doing the Python-CGI-calls-Perl-CGI I'll be happy to consider that the "answer".

Just know that my goal is to make little (ideally no) changes to the standard Mailman installation.  Copying the "private" cgi-bin script (whose source is mailman-2.1.12/Mailman/Cgi/private.py) and making changes to call swish.cgi is cool, but modifying the existing private cgi-bin script wouldn't really be cool.

---

Here's what I did to test the answer (using `os.execv` to replace the python script with the perl script, so that the perl script will inherit the python script's environment):

I created a **pythontest** script with:

```
import os
os.environ['FOO'] = 'BAR'
mydir = os.path.dirname(os.environ.get('SCRIPT_FILENAME'))
childprog = mydir + '/perltest'
childargs = []
os.execv(childprog, childargs)
```

Then a **perltest** script with:

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
while (($key,$value) = each %ENV) {
  print "<p>$key=$value</p>\n";
}
```

Then I called http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/pythontest and saw that the environment printout included the custom FOO variable so the child perltest process had successfully inherited all the environment variables.

Comment: Why not just use a Python interface to Swish? http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Swish-E/0.5

Comment: That's an excellent second option. Going to try just calling swish.cgi first though because it requires less custom coding. swish.cgi comes with Swish and generates the search interface (query box and options). If I used the Python interface to Swish I believe I'd have to re-implement all that. Plus if we upgrade Swish in the future, we'd get any improvements to swish.cgi automatically. But thank you - if this (Python CGI calls swish.cgi Perl CGI) doesn't work, that's an excellent backup plan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to state the obvious here because I don't have any detailed knowledge about your specific environment.

If your python script is a genuine CGI and not a mod_python script or similar then it is just a regular process spawned to handle the one request. You can use `os.execv` to replace it with another process (e.g. the perl CGI) and the new process will inherit the current process' environment, `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. This assumes that you don't need to read `stdin` for your security checks. It may also depend on whether your CGI is running in a restricted environment. `execv` is potentially dangerous and might be blocked in such an environment.

If you're running from a mod_python environment or if you need to peek at posted data (i.e. `stdin`) then the execv approach isn't available to you. You have two main alternatives.

You could run the perl CGI directly (e.g. look at the `subprocess` module) handing it a correct environment and feeding it the correct data to its `stdin`. You can the spool the returned data from its `stdout` raw (or cooked if needed) directly back to the web server.

Otherwise, you could make a local web request to run the CGI. This is likely to require a bit less knowledge about the server setup, but a bit more work in the python CGI to make and handle the HTTP request.

Comment: No, I believe the security checks use the cookie data which shows up in the environment as HTTP_COOKIE and is thus passed in - so stdin isn't an issue.

Your solution seems to work - I am going to post a follow up to provide more info in case anyone else has a similar question in the future, then I will accept your answer. Thanks! :)